# What does "active threads" mean in ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I have ThreadPoolExecutor whith next params:

```
corePoolSize = 20
maximumPoolSize = 100
workQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue(10)
```

Each second I submit 1k tasks. Tasks represent some IO operation which takes 1-2s. Some of them get rejected. It's expected.
I log the thread pool state before rejection using custom AbortPolicy.

In logs I see something I cannot explain. Messages like:

> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@3e6be2d8[Running, pool size = 100, **active threads = 2**, queued tasks = 10, completed tasks = 4471827].

I've found in docs that `getActiveCount` method `Returns the approximate number of threads that are actively executing tasks.` But it does not help me to understand...

What does "active threads" mean here? And why only 2 threads are active while pool has reached its limit, queue is full and the task is rejected?

I want to increase `maximumPoolSize` to process more tasks at once but firstly I need to understand whether I use ThreadPool resources efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Active thread" means a thread that has started executing a task from the work queue.

When threads are started or become free, they don't pick up a task "immediately" - there's contention to read from the queue. If you submit 100 tasks to the executor in a tight loop, it's likely that by the end only a few worker threads have had the chance to pick up a task.

To get a better picture of how many threads are actually running tasks, log the active thread count on a regular schedule, for example 10 times per second.

Comment: Good Answer except for the last part. Why do you say, “need at least 1-2k threads”?

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm assuming the OP wants to provide service for the 1000 tasks they are submitting every second. I'll clarify

Comment: The tasks *will* be serviced with a few threads. You need not have as many threads as tasks. That is the very purpose of the Executors framework. The first part of your Answer would suggest that you understand that. So I must be misunderstanding the second part of your Answer.

Comment: I submit 1k tasks. I expect that 20 (core pool size) of them start executing immediately, 10 (queue size) go to workQueue, 80 will cause the new thread creation and start executing as well. 890 tasks will be rejected and in logs will be "active threads" number more or less equal to 100 (max pool size). Like, all threads are busy.

Thread blocked by IO, or Parked thread counted as active as well?

Comment: @MikeYakovets That is what I would expect as well, except for "active threads" being logged as 100 or near 100\. Is that not what you are seeing? Threads blocked by IO will be counted as active, yes.

Comment: I log ThreadPool on each rejection. Most of the time TP has 1-5 active threads and quite a few with 20-100 active threads.
Should it be near 100, or should I config (maybe increase queue size?) TP to make it close to 100 active threads?

Comment: By logging the active thread count when tasks are rejected, it's likely you will log many messages before many threads have started to run the tasks. If you want a better picture of how many threads are actually running tasks, log the active thread count on a regular schedule, for example 10 times per second.

Comment: @BasilBourque I've removed the part you find confusing, as it doesn't seem to apply to the OP's situation. Perhaps you have overlooked the fact that the OP has a *bounded* work queue and is adding tasks at a much higher rate than can be cleared by the thread pool?

Comment: Are you sure active threads are not actually limited by CPU cores? I can't get this metric get any further than my CPU cores (8), with far higher core-sizes, etc.